# What proof type is best for math competitions?

Tags: proof-writing, contest-math

What proof type is best for essay mathematics competitions like USAJMO, USAMO, and IMO? How can you get used to writing proofs?

Comment: The proof type that works.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. I’m voting to close this question because it is too general. If you have a particular problem and several ways to prove it and ask us which kind of proof is better for your competition purposes we may be able to help you.

Comment: Everything [herein](https://amazon.co.uk/dp/0387982191), e.g. [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta_jumping).

Answer (score 1):

Generally just practice as much as you can. There are several articles written by experienced math olympiad participants that can help; some of them are [How to Write a Math Solution (by AoPS)](https://artofproblemsolving.com/news/articles/how-to-write-a-solution), [Remarks on English (by Evan Chen)](https://web.evanchen.cc/handouts/english/english.pdf), and [How To Write Proofs](http://zimmer.csufresno.edu/%7Elarryc/proofs/proofs.html). There are also programs that prepare you for math olympiads, such as [WOOT](https://artofproblemsolving.com/school/woot.php).